# How to list the AWS services I'm paying for

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I'm stuck with the AWS service. I can't find what services are being turned on.  I can't find them, even I can't see why the number of services is increasing over time and I am being charged. Please help me.

I have deleted the S3 buckets I started and closed two EFS instances from the AWS console. But still, I am being charged.

Comment: Please show the contents of the "Bills" section in your Billing Console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) to remove resources in your account. Simple to use and support many services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the AWS cost-explorer dashboard? Please check the same and see which services are being charged today. Go and delete them if you are not using them.

If you don't want any AWS service, go and suspend your AWS account. :P

If you want more help.. contact us on https://www.cloudkaramchari.com/contact/

#Cloudkaramchari